# Groovy app and mysql connection - "No suitable ClassLoader found for grab"

Tags: mysql, groovy

I'm trying to create an simple app with mysql connection in groovy. I've read that if I want to use mysql driver, I need to add the annotation:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.32'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
])
```

but compilation throws an error:

> No suitable ClassLoader found for grab

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Should I add `mysql-connector-java:5.1.32.jar` as an external library in my project?

That's my code:

```
package mypackage

@Grapes([
    @Grab('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.32'),
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
])

import groovy.sql.Sql;

class DbConnection {

    private Sql connection;

    def connect() {
         def db = [url:'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb', user:'sa', password:'', driver:'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver']
        connection = Sql.newInstance(db)
    }

    def close(){
        connection.close()      
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of groovy You use? With `2.4.0-beta-2` it works fine excepting the fact that I've no MySQL server installed.

Comment: @Opal i'm using `2.3.6`. I will try with another version

Comment: @Opal same effect with `2.4.0-beta-3`. Maybe something is wrong with my system class loader? `print ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getClass().getName()` tells it is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`. Is it ok?

Comment: I also get `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`. I suppose it's ok.

Comment: Do You really need this line? Comment it out.

Comment: @Opal I've solved the problem by creating Maven project. I think my IDEs (both ggts and idea) used java compiler instead of groovyc to build the application and that was the reason of the problem. Maven builds everything correct. I'm linking to my `pom` - for the further visitors: http://pastebin.com/EyVcEUWS